# Suppose I want to customize the look and feel of my website for my corporate clients

Tags: design-patterns, templates, customization, webforms

Given:

- I have a website that includes both ASP.NET Web Forms and Classic ASP web pages.
- Multiple companies are willing to pay to **customize** the look and feel of this website.

Question:

> Are there any well known design-patterns, books, or online resources that detail customization best-practices?

**EDIT**: Are ashx handlers a good way to render custom images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

[User Interface Design Tips, Techniques, and Principles](http://www.ambysoft.com/essays/userInterfaceDesign.html)